# Self-referencing table, parent/child insert statement in a single query

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, hierarchical-data, self-reference

I have a self-referencing table, and I am wanting add both the parent and child examples in a single query. Is there a better way to do it then to break it down in a fashion similar to what I have below?

```
+---------------------+
|       example       |
+---------+-----------+
|   id    | parent_id |
+---------+-----------+
|    1    |           |
|    2    |     1     |
|    3    |     1     |
|    4    |     1     |
|    5    |           |
|    6    |     5     |
|    7    |     5     |
+---------+-----------+

DECLARE example_id INT;

INSERT INTO `example` (parent_id) VALUE("");

SET example_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO `example` (parent_id) VALUE (example_id);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to tree structure with your question you should better check [this article](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/). If you would only have 1 level of children for parent then your way is possibly the simplest way around.

Comment: I would have an unlimited amount of children per parent. Thanks for the link.

Comment: OP already showed in the example that he has multiple childern per parent.

Comment: There was a miss written statement, I meant 1 level in tree structure. Fixing it right now; sorry about it

Comment: In that case the tree structure can have unlimited tiers as well. Though it should only have four at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Your way of doing things looks OK.
In a real-world example you'll probably do an `insert - select` based on some criteria.

```
INSERT INTO example SELECT 
  null as id 
  ,e.id as parent_id
  ,10 as field1
  ,....
FROM example e WHERE e.somefield = 10 ORDER BY e.id DESC LIMIT 1;
```